# How do you make instance variable in a controller and use the instance variable in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to know if a directory is empty so as they will not be displayed.

Trying to store: If a directory has files; Then I will call it in the view.

```
def index
    @filter = params[:filter]
    @type = params[:type]
    @content = []

if @filter
directory_path = "public/files/marketing/voip"
directory = Dir.glob("#{directory_path}/#{@filter}/#{@type}")
directory.each do |data|
if File.exists?(data) && !File.directory?(data)

    @content = Array.new("#{@type}")

end
@view = 'types'
end
end
```

I am not sure how to store the information, here I want to store the @type of only empty directories.

Then call @content in the view to display the directories that have the @type I stored.

Comment: Can you provide more context and perhaps a specific question? Any instance variable created in a controller is available in the corresponding view.

Comment: I want to display directories on a web browser that not empty. The directories that have files in them will be displayed. Here I am trying to store the 'at'type of the directory for every directory that is not empty. So say I had 2 folders, a=empty;b=full. I scan both. I store the value "b". "b" would be the 'at'type. Then in my view I can use the stored values to only display those @type of directories that are full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked:

```
@view = 'types'

            #Loop through directories to see if files exist
        #If files exist add directory name to @array
        @directories = Array.new
        @all_directories = Dir.glob("public/files/marketing/voip/#{@filter}/*")
        @all_directories.each do |directory|
            base_directory = Dir.glob("#{directory}/*")

            unless base_directory.empty?
                @directories.push(File.basename(directory))
            end
```

This goes through each directory and if its not empty pushes the basename to my array.

Answer (score 1):

1) Why are you checking if File.exists?  You just globbed the directory, so each item in the results does in fact exist.

2)

> I want to store the @type of only empty directories.

```
@empty_dir_types = []

...


  fname = "...."

  if Dir.entries(fname).empty? 
    @empty_dir_types << File.basename fname
  end
```

Or,

```
@type = params[:type]
@empty_dir_types = []

...

  fname = "...."

  if Dir.entries(fname).empty? 
    @empty_dir_types << @type
  end
```

Or,

```
@type = params[:type]
@empty_dir_type = nil

fname = "...."

if Dir.entries(fname).empty? 
  @empty_dir_type = @type
end
```

Comment: Is the fname my directory? Do I not need the directory = Dir.glob(...  ? Or the .each do |data| ?

Comment: @DDDD: Yes, fname is short for filename, and in the unix world filename means either a directory name or a filename. Assign whatever directory you want to search to fname.  Or, use your own variable name: `directory = "#{directory_path}/#{@filter}/#{@type}"`  Dir.entries is similar to Dir.glob, but Dir.entries also returns hidden files, i.e. filenames beginning with a dot, e.g. `.bash_profile`. You do not need to call each(), you can just write `if Dir.glob(directory).empty?` Dir.glob returns an array--if it's empty, the directory is empty(accept for hidden files).

Comment: Does this search through all the directories in the main "directory_path" ?